# Storing audit logs on GCP

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

I would like to store audit logs on our GCP cluster (where our app is). There are different storage/db options out there. We are looking into one table, bucket on similar without some relationships.

Background: we are delivering enterprise high-scale saas solution
What I need to do with our audit logs write, search them by audit logs fields/columns and to combine (AND, OR). Also sort options are important.

I focused on following options (please let me know if there is something else that matches better)

1. Cloud Storage
2. Cloud Firestore
3. GCP managed Atlas Kafka

Our requirements are:

1. to have a scalable and high performance storage
2. that data are encrypted at rest
3. to have search capability (full test search will be perfect but I'm good with simple search by column/filed)

What I've found so far from requirements point:

1. Mongo has greater performances then Firebase. Not sure comparing Cloud Storage (standard mode) with Mongo.
2. Cloud Storage and Cloud Firestore do encrypt data. Not sure about Mongo
3. Cloud Firestore  and Mongo have search capability out of the box (not full text search). Cloud Storage has search with the BigQuery and over the permanent/temp tables.

My god-feeling is that Cloud Storage is not the best choice. I think that search capability is kind of cumbersome. Also that's document based structure for large binary docs (images, videos). Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Last 2 are more close to the matching solution. From the enterprise standpoint Mongo looks closer.

Please let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

Use BigQuery! You can [sink the logs directly in BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2). In GCP, all the data are encrypted at rest. BigQuery is a powerful datawarehouse with strong query capacity. All your requirement are met with this solution.

Comment: Our audit microservice will write audit logs to the target storage/destination (any solution). Mentioned sink link is related to the standard logs received by FluentD/Stackdriver agents that are routed to the BQ or Cloud storage.
BigQuery is interesting.  Does it make sense to write audit logs as JSONs to Cloud Storage and then to search against them with BQ? Or to create data source in BQ and to write directly in it?
I got that BQ is more for analytics, aggregate functions and it's great with cold data (not frequent changes).

Comment: Personally, I recommend you to put all your data in BigQuery. After 90days, the storage cost decreases automatically. If you query file stored in GCS, the query are slower, and without real advantage. If you want to clean your logs, you can run schedule queries to transform your data and sink the result in another table. And then delete the older raw logs in the first table. BigQuery possibilities are strong, it's one of my favorite product on GCP!

Comment: One doubt that I have is that BQ is OLAP oriented (it has great results there and it is column base, great for aggregate functions). But we are looking at OLTP operations, e.g. give me audits logs for this user for last 10 days from words and ASC.

Comment: BigQuery isn't a relational database, that means you haven't relation between table, I mean relation checked automatically by the engine. So, you can have duplicated entries for the same "primary key" or broken "foreign key". However, you can perform the same SQL requests as any engine that support SQL2011.